# exploit the function "tabulate"

Tags: r

I run

```
tf<- tablulate(x):

[1] 75 24 19  1  1
```

and tried to make a loop "for" to get the "maximum" of each element on the "tabulate result" as following:

```
for (element in tf)
{
+ b= max(table(x[element]))
+ print (b)
+ }
```

I don't get the expected result, it is probably simple but not really for me. I tried this:

```
> max(table(x[1:75]))
[1] 72
> max(table(x[76:99]))
[1] 11
> max(table(x[100:118]))
and so on ...........
```

It's working and I have what I expected but it's really long and not fun if I have big dataset.

Comment: Do you have any patterns to cut the variable i.e. `1:75, 76:99, 100:118` seems variable

Comment: No; this just a sum => 1 :75; 1+75:75+24; 1+75+24:75+24+19 & so on...

Comment: It is easy to do. `tf <- c(75, 24, 19, 1, 1); v1 <- cumsum(tf); v2 <- c(1,v1[-length(v1)]+1);  Map(function(i,j) table(x[seq(i,j)]), v2, v1)`

Comment: The part with "Map" doesn't work

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific than `doesn't work`.  I am not getting any errors.  ` Map(function(i,j) max(table(x[seq(i,j)])), v2, v1)`  It would also help if you show a reproducible example with expected result.  At present, `x` is not shown.

Comment: `Map(function(i,j) max(table(x[seq(i,j)])), v2, v1)` work. Thanks

Comment: Posted my comments as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
 tf <- c(75, 24, 19, 1, 1)
 v1 <- cumsum(tf)
 v2 <- c(1,v1[-length(v1)]+1)
 Map(function(i,j) max(table(x[seq(i,j)])), v2, v1)
```